# How to adjust generic types for a TypeScript function with complex object structure?

Tags: typescript

I have the following TypeScript code snippet:

```js
type Query = {
  model: string;
  on: string;
  fields: string[];
  query?: Query[];
};

function getModel(config: {
  object: xmlrpc.Client
  db: string
  userId: number
  password: string
}) {
  return <T extends { [key: string]: any }>(
    model: string,
    fields: Extract<keyof T, string>[],
    props?: {
      offset?: number
      limit?: number
      where?: [string, string, any][]
      query?: Query[]
    }
  ): Promise<(T & { id: number })[]> =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      // Implementation details
    }).then(async (res) => {
      // Post-processing logic
    });
}
```

When calling `getModel`, the inferred type for `result` is not matching my expectations. Here's how I'm calling the function:

```js
const config = { object, db, userId, password };

const result = await getModel(config)(
  "product.template",
  ["name", "categ_id", "attribute_line_ids", "service_type"],
  {
    limit: 5,
    where: [["categ_id", "=", 40]],
    query: [
      {
        model: "product.template.attribute.line",
        on: "attribute_line_ids",
        fields: ["value_ids"],
        query: [
          {
            model: "product.attribute.value",
            on: "value_ids",
            fields: ["name"],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  }
);
```

I'm expecting the type of `result` to be:

```js
const result: ({
  name: any
  categ_id: any
  attribute_line_ids: ({ value_ids: ({ name: any } & { id: number })[] } & {
    id: number
  })[]
  service_type: any
} & { id: number })[]
```

How can I adjust the generic type definition to ensure that the inferred type matches the expected structure?

Comment: ① Please [edit] your code to be a [mre] (e.g., if you have no problem with the runtime behavior, maybe you should just leave it out, and ask how to write the call signature so the types are what you expect). ② Please [include any relevant information from your image as plaintext](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218). ③ You seem to be asking for two things: one is to fix the output type, and the other is to constrain the input.  You should consider breaking this into two questions, since each one has its own independent answer ⊛ I'll check back if I see an edit here; good luck!

Comment: @jcalz okay, let me edit the question

Comment: Hmm, I think it would have helped if you explained *why* you expected that type, since it involves checking sub-sub-properties of the query.  I hope I understand what you're doing... so, uh, is [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WkzpLm) what you're looking for? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thank you for sharing the approach. I've explored the link you provided, and it indeed addresses my issue perfectly.

Comment: To provide more specific information about the output type, every invocation of the `getModel` function results in an array of objects where the properties correspond to the fields provided, along with an additional `id` property.

Comment: For example: `const result = await getModel(config)('product.template', ['name', 'categ_id']); // Output: { id: number; name: any; categ_id: any; }[]`

Comment: However, when a query is included, the function executes recursively until there are no more queries to process. In this case, the output becomes nested within the property named as specified in the `on` property of the query object

Comment: For example: `const result = await getModel(config)('product.template', ['name', 'attribute_line_ids'], {
  query: [
    {
      model: 'product.template.attribute.line',
      on: 'attribute_line_ids',
      fields: ['value_ids']
    }
  ]
}); // Output: { id: number; name: any; attribute_line_ids: { id: number; value_ids: any }[] }[]`

Comment: Additionally, I also intend for the type inference to be done manually, like this:

`const result = await getModel(config)<{name: string; attribute_line_ids: {value_ids:number[]}}>('product.template', ['name', 'attribute_line_ids'], {query:[{model:'product.template.attribute.line',on:'attribute_line_ids',fields: ['value_ids']}]})`

Comment: With this manual type inference, the output type will no longer be `any`, but instead:

`// Output: { id: number; name: string; attribute_line_ids: { id: number; value_ids: number[] }[] }[]`

Comment: This approach allows for a more precise definition of the output type, as we determine it after executing the function.

Comment: That's a lot of comments and I'm not sure what you want me to do with them, sorry. If this information is important for the question as asked, please [edit] the question to include it. Is it okay if I post my answer to the question using the `any` version, and if you can't figure out how to extend it, you open up a new question about it?

Comment: Sure, no problem at all. That's already sufficient to assist me. Thank you for your willingness to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for this to work, you'd need `getModel()` to be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type of the `query` property of the input as well as the type of `fields`.  Let's give a name to the shape of a query so we can re-use it:

```
interface Query {
    model: string;
    on: string;
    fields: string[];
    query?: Query[];
};
```

Then when you call `getModel()` with a query of generic type `Q[]` and `fields` of generic type `K[]`, you want the output to be of type `Queried<Q, K>`, which will end up being recursive so that we can drill down into `Q`.  Here's one possible way to write that:

```
type Queried<Q extends Query, K extends string> = [K] extends [never] ? any :
    ({ [P in K]:
        Queried<NonNullable<Extract<Q, { on: P }>["query"]>[number],
            Extract<Q, { on: P }>["fields"][number]>
    } & { id: number })[]
```

The first thing we do is just return `any` if the query has no fields `K`, which is the base case of our recursion.  Otherwise, we need to produce an array of objects with a numeric `id` property as well as all the properties in `K`.  For each property key `P` in `K`, we need to find the member of `Q` (which could be a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types)) whose `on` field corresponds to `P`, if it exists. I'm using [the `Extract` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) for that.  And then we just recurse on that member, using the elements of its `query` property as the new `Q`, and the elements of its `fields` property as the new `K`.

Oh, and `getModel()` looks like this (I removed its `config` input since it's not needed for this demo):

```
function getModel() {
    return <K extends string, const Q extends Query>(
        model: string,
        fields: K[],
        props?: {
            offset?: number
            limit?: number
            where?: [string, string, any][]
            query?: Q[]
        }
    ): Promise<Queried<Q, K>> =>
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            throw 1;
        }).then(async (res) => {
            throw 2;
        });
}
```

Let's test it on your example. We make the call:

```
const result = await getModel()(
    "product.template",
    ["name", "categ_id", "attribute_line_ids", "service_type"],
    {
        limit: 5,
        where: [["categ_id", "=", 40]],
        query: [
            {
                model: "product.template.attribute.line",
                on: "attribute_line_ids",
                fields: ["value_ids"],
                query: [
                    {
                        model: "product.attribute.value",
                        on: "value_ids",
                        fields: ["name"],
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    }
);
```

and the result is of type

```
/* const result: ({
    name: any;
    categ_id: any;
    attribute_line_ids: ({
        value_ids: ({
            name: any;
        } & {
            id: number;
        })[];
    } & {
        id: number;
    })[];
    service_type: any;
} & {
    id: number;
})[] */
```

which is exactly what you asked for.

---

Note that it it's possible to try to augment this type to allow for some non-`any` types at the leaf nodes of the object tree, or have it pick from some known object type, but that's outside the scope of this question.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKFEsDsBcFMCcBmBDAxrABARQK4IJ4YDeoGZGAtgPYAmsANgFwYDO08UA5gNynlWRmbDpB58yicAxosh7LgG0AurxDkMARzzx8Afma4Cy1QF9VoaPgAOmQx1g0APFgywAHnEgzs2-ABoMAGlXD1gvFlZ5UQA+DABeDAVApRDPbwVIWAA3BBTdDGRIQkZxDAAKIkSABQwoIKUStXVyOyknADkBdpx6emQAI3pYRwBRD3g0aGcAyoFmGpNohQAiLQJlpSXIHAp+3L9S5vIx9knp4gw5jAWl5clpFg2Mnb34TdKTDAAyC-AaZm2uwQGBMAEplKBQIgcJBUNBwAIMJxYNAALK0BhlUHEUrwFE4eCQDCOYLuNIRYRcAKoARsbCpMLeOz4aJlQ7kah0JiREScA5NI73egyZiBZT8o5kKzwKhWFj6HECyVkKiIRAsFEKwGvdlHejgCjgaBal4IXXNADuAAsELAFQpKaIAo6+QUikoIUrlWsdAqsJ7lSZSqD5jLDRrnNo2udAtFYnFoubMhbrmHwBqymU8SwqPQcgE8QArWBw7EJxXK9TQK0ylMARlUgdBADpq2EysgWPhYeVs2XYiQvZLq7WMAAmRuSsGmSFgECd7uoDDQ2HwxGIKhULEV8g0yB07M9aDxAoW5BGpEo9FcrFsodkZbS2g4OGt2AUKx9ODLCWSlaQZAKFgH8MGWVBkDgTgAH0-hA5YIPkfocDgKD9UyGCZDgjV4CycB0CgywbA2X8jkHStyH1Q1oGYABWEjK2tW1mAUFZwMgjC4LiECABYAAYlCUejvV8ZjzWVMjyMrTkGGYR8ZRoF9oDfD8v1gZsEI4JC4GbNDgKEyT1CueDoEQ5DYFQqBzL+R59IMiQpGFWREmWLJkHoPAMMeQSxMkn18FE+87PUCSgoM6TuTk59Xw08AtLU1z3L0nzQv4QRQISjzrJ-ZKUuXByRWcgCgOInKDJMWy7O8wLAwq9QqsDYMZxAAB6AAqDA9wPWAWCPZgKlKIrYGYQp8EnMg2NgaC-mGooxoKEzNLMiz0OsvqQuaDKrIK-rqvIQaZtG81Ph+dblWmjBtQQOb1DBYwPm+HcjnOy74Dm26VFKbDcPwwihrdQ6QGOx7an+C7TVe0B3owVrmtnIA)

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation and solution! You truly saved my life by helping me understand and implement this. I'll give it a try to see if I can extend the type to accommodate non-any types at the leaf nodes or pick from known object types, as you mentioned. If I encounter any difficulties and can't figure out how to extend it, I'll open a new question for further assistance. Thanks again for your help!